# App delegate issues with multiple view controllers

Tags: ios

I created tab bar controller and implemented in app delegate but before that i also implemented other view controller.i don't know how to use call them orderly.please tell me how to make them arrange as i like.

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
{
    UINavigationController *navigation;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) JASidePanelController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *this;


@end

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[ViewController alloc] init]];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigation;

//UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
//        self.window = window;

    self.viewController = [[JASidePanelController alloc] init];
    self.viewController.shouldDelegateAutorotateToVisiblePanel = NO;

    self.viewController.leftPanel = [[LeftViewController alloc] init];



    UIViewController *viewcontroller1=[[HomeView alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller2=[[Speciality alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller3=[[Activity alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller4 =[[Notification alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller5 =[[Profile alloc]init];

    viewcontroller1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    viewcontroller2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    viewcontroller3.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    viewcontroller4.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    viewcontroller5.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];



    UINavigationController *navcontroller1=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller1];
    UINavigationController *navcontroller2=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller2];
    UINavigationController *navcontroller3=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller3];
    UINavigationController *navcontroller4 =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller4];
    UINavigationController *navcontroller5 =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller5];


    viewcontroller1.title = @"Home";
    viewcontroller2.title = @"Speciality";
    viewcontroller3.title = @"Activity";
    viewcontroller4.title = @"Notification";
    viewcontroller5.title = @"Profile";

    navcontroller1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home"];
    navcontroller2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"special"];
    navcontroller3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"activity"];
    navcontroller4.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notify"];
    navcontroller5.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pro"];

    self.this = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    self.this.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navcontroller1,navcontroller2,navcontroller3,navcontroller4,navcontroller5, nil];

    self.this.tabBar.barTintColor =  RGBCOLOR(249, 178, 131);

    self.viewController.centerPanel = _this;


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you set the window's root controller to a navigation controller:

```
self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
```

And then you go on to instantiate a handful of other nav controllers and add them to a tab controller. It's not clear from your question what you're trying to achieve, but if you want your app to use a tab controller, you'll want to set your window's root controller to the tab controller, not a navigation controller.

Comment: No i am actually using tab bar controller in my app but before that log in page,sign up page have to come but if i import this in app delegate only tab bar controller comes bfr everything